# Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined with ReactTable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-table

I installed ReactTable using NPM and then I imported it in a react application. The page is working fine if I don't try to use the component, however, as soon as I try to use it I get the error from the title.

This is the code I currently have.

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'

const data = [{
    name: 'Tanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
      name: 'Jason Maurer',
      age: 23,
    }
  }]

  const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
  }, {
    id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
    Header: 'Friend Name',
    accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
    accessor: 'friend.age'
  }]

const VariableTable = ({ readOnly, correct, incorrect, active, variables, steps, create, update, onActiveChange }) => console.log(data) || (
  <div className="VariableTable card">

/* Some other HTML and JSX in here */

    <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns}/>
  </div>
)
```

It's basically the demo they provide here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#columns

It also compiles just fine.

Am I supposed to change any other files within the React project?

Thanks.

Comment: yous initial `data` inside the VariableTable may be undefined

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe you are missing something, i have created [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bardeen-2tl1q) for you

Hope it helps

Comment: Well the thing is in your example you load that component straight onto the root whereas in my case the ReactTable is part of a component that is loaded on a chain of other components. Do you think this could cause any issues?

Comment: i would have to see what's happening there, can you create a sandbox snippet of your problem ?

Comment: I've chose to create my own class using a standard HTML table since the ReactTable has taken way too much time. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you installed V7 of ReactTable but have code that works with V6 (which apparently is very different from V7).  Also note that as of yesterday the default installation for react-table is version 7-beta, so if you want to use V6 you need to lock into a version.

For your reference:

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1556

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1686